# How to match the unique ids that I created in df1 to df2 based on two column values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bigdata, data-analysis

I have two dataframes, and I am struggling to match the unique ids that I created in df1 to df2 based on 'name' and 'version' values. I need to add a column to df2, let's call it ['ID'], whose values match with the unique id values in df1. The condition is that both the 'name' and 'version' values in df2 must equal the same 'name' and 'version' in df1 in order to be assigned the correct ID value. DF2 has all the elements of DF1 but they are repeated.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Unique ID': ['111', '222', '333', '444'],
        'Name': ['A', 'A' ,'B','C'],
        'Version': ['1.1', '1.2', '1.0', '1.1'],
        'x': ['...', '...', '...', '...']
    }
)
```

DF1

```
   | UNIQUE ID | NAME | VERSION |  X  |
  1|     111   |   A  |     1.1 | ... |
  2|     222   |   A  |     1.2 | ... |
  3|     333   |   B  |     1.0 | ... |
  4|     444   |   C  |     1.1 | ... |
```

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Name': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B'],
        'Version': [ '1.1' ,'1.1', '1.1', '1.2', '1.0'],
        'x': ['...', '...', '...', '...','...'],
        'x': ['...', '...', '...', '...','...'],
    }
)
```

DF2

```
    | NAME | VERSION |  X  | X  |
  1 |  A   |  1.1    | ... |... |
  2 |  A   |  1.1    | ... |... | 
  3 |  A   |  1.1    | ... |... |  
  4 |  A   |  1.2    | ... |... |
  5 |  B   |  1.0    | ... |... |
```

**Desired Output for DF2:**

DF2

```
    | NAME | VERSION |   ID    | X  |  X |
  1 |  A   |  1.1    |   111   |... | ...|
  2 |  A   |  1.1    |   111   |... | ...|
  3 |  A   |  1.1    |   111   |... | ...|
  4 |  A   |  1.2    |   222   |... | ...|
  5 |  B   |  1.0    |   333   |... | ...|
```

**Attempted code:**

```
df2['ID'] = df1[df1['name' + '_' + 'version'].isin(df2['name' + '_' + 'version'])]['Unique ID'].values
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way which is a little bit dirty but works :

```
df2.merge(df1[['Unique ID','Name','Version']],left_on=['Name','Version'], right_on=['Name','Version'],
suffixes=('_left', '_right'))
```

Comment: I want to assign the unique ids created in df1 into df2 for the corresponding values, where name and version in df1 == name and version in df2.  I am only concerned with the name and version columns at this point.

Comment: could you give an example with pd.Dataframe to replicate your problem please

Comment: I edited the question, I hope it makes more sense now.